# Given a binary column in a pandas dataframe, how I change the preceding 0 to 1?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binary

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"first_name": ["Alexander", "Alan", "Heather", "Marion", "Amy", "John"],
            "last_name": ["Miller", "Jacobson", ".", "Milner", "Cooze", "Smith"],
            "age": [42, 52, 36, 24, 73, 19],
                "marriage_status" : [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

  age first_name last_name  marriage_status
0   42  Alexander    Miller                0
1   52       Alan  Jacobson                0
2   36    Heather         .                1
3   24     Marion    Milner                1
4   73        Amy     Cooze                0
5   19       John     Smith                1
....
```

The column `marriage_status` is a column of binary data, 0 and 1. Before each `1`, I would like to make the preceding row a `1` as well. In this example, the dataframe would become:

```
  age first_name last_name  marriage_status
0   42  Alexander    Miller                0
1   52       Alan  Jacobson                1   # this changed to 1
2   36    Heather         .                1
3   24     Marion    Milner                1
4   73        Amy     Cooze                1   # this changed to 1
5   19       John     Smith                1
....
```

In other words, there are "groups" of consecutive ones in this column, and I woudl like to make the preceding row element 1 instead of 0. How can I do this?

My thought was to somehow create a for statement, but this isn't a pandas-based solution. One could also try `enumerate()`, but then I need to make the preceding value 1; without addition, I'm not sure how this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the `or` operator `|`.  It will treat the `1`s as `True` and `0`s as `False`.  `|` with evaluate to `False` when we have a `0` in a row and a `0` in the next row.

```
df.marriage_status = (
    df.marriage_status | df.marriage_status.shift(-1)
).astype(int)

df

   age first_name last_name  marriage_status
0   42  Alexander    Miller                0
1   52       Alan  Jacobson                1
2   36    Heather         .                1
3   24     Marion    Milner                1
4   73        Amy     Cooze                1
5   19       John     Smith                1
```

Comment: Can you explain the `|` for me?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang yes!  one moment.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang , it's just a "or" operation: if the field in current row or next row has non zero value, then it will be non-zero, which is 1 here. you can try: print( 1 | 1)

Comment: @Windchill I was just curious what the rationale behind using `|` was.

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks for the help! It's great when posters help explain their answer for learning purposes.

Comment: I actually got a TypeError with the above: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'float' and 'bool'`. Unique values are `array([ nan,   0.,   1.])`

Comment: @ShanZhengYang you have missing values... you can use this as one way to fix it `df.marriage_status.astype(bool) | df.marriage_status.shift(-1)`

Comment: @piRSquared You're right, there were `NaN` values. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can use [Series.shift(-1)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) method:

```
In [21]: df.loc[df.marriage_status.shift(-1) == 1, 'marriage_status'] = 1

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
   age first_name last_name  marriage_status
0   42  Alexander    Miller                0
1   52       Alan  Jacobson                1
2   36    Heather         .                1
3   24     Marion    Milner                1
4   73        Amy     Cooze                1
5   19       John     Smith                1
```